# Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RSPerl', details:

Tags: r, perl-module

I have been trying to install the package RSPerl  with  the command where I have R 2.15.3 and Perl 5.10 :

```
PERL=`which perl` R --vanilla CMD INSTALL -c -l ~/library/ RSPerl_0.92-1.tar.gz
```

I am getting this error:

```
Warning: /tmp/RtmpQZ3PRs/R.INSTALL146277fe434b/RSPerl/man/PerlReferenceObjects.Rd:32: unknown macro '\textit'
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
Removing additional files
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RSPerl', details:
  call: setPerlLib(FALSE)
  error: could not find function "Sys.putenv"
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/AVT2130/software/R-2.15.3/library/RSPerl
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Thank you,

Comment: `Sys.putenv` was made defunct in R 2.15 according to `?"base-defunct"` If you are keen to use old versions of R, try 2.14. But these are pretty old versions of R. Probably better to find a solution that doesn't depend on an outdated package.

Comment: (But perhaps you can use `Sys.setenv` instead of `Sys.putenv`.)